# Is it possible to force multiple python processes to share the same memory via a C++ extension?

Tags: python, c++, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, boost-python

Here is my attempt:

```
int* globalvar = new int[8];
void cpp_init(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        globalvar[i] = 0;
}
void writeAtIndex(int index, int value){
    globalvar[index] = value;
}
int accessIndex(int index){
    return globalvar[index];
}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MpUtils){
    def("cpp_init", &cpp_init);
    def("writeAtIndex", &writeAtIndex);
    def("accessIndex", &accessIndex);
}
```

and in the python file

```
def do_stuff(index):
    writeAtIndex(index, randint(1, 100))
    time.sleep(index/10)
    print([accessIndex(i) for i in range(8)])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    processes = []
    cpp_init()
    for i in range(0, 10):
        processes.append( Process( target=do_stuff, args=(i,) ) )
    for process in processes:
        process.start()
    for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

And the output is this:

```
[48, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 88, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 59, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 26]
```

Could someone explain why this is not working? I tried printing the globalvar and it's always the same value. There shouldn't be any race conditions as wating for 0.1 to 0.8 seconds should be more than enough to make the computer write something. Shouldn't C++ be accessing directly the location of the pointer?

Thanks

Comment: Processes don't generally share (writable) memory, even if they're native.  Have you tried using something like mmap() to make an actual shared memory space?  In C++ `global` means global in a process, not across several processes.  If you use threads, it would be shared.

Comment: I've already done it before with the Multiprocessing module in Python but it's kinda slow, so I'm wondering if it's possible to bypass all that and directly access a memory location (if my understanding of pointers is correct, it points to a memory location of a variable)

Comment: Processes have separate address spaces. Address 0x100 in one process is separate from 0x100 in another. There are ways to share memory between processes but those require extra setup and usually synchronization.

Comment: Yes, you have to use something from the OS to share memory between processes.  Check out the documents for mmap to create a shared space, but beware, synchronization is a difficult problem.

Comment: As you already use boost you can try [boost interprocess](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/interprocess.html). It will let you create and access shared memory from c++ and then you can expose this functionality to python via boost python as you already tried.

Comment: @Voo didn't know that before, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processes can generally access only their own memory space.
You can possibly use the [shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html#multiprocessing.shared_memory.SharedMemory) module of multiprocessing to share the same array across processes. See example in the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

The following loop will create a list of processes with consecutive first `args`, from `0` to `9`. (First process has `0`, second one `1` and so on.)

```
    for i in range(0, 10):
        processes.append( Process( target=do_stuff, args=(i,) ) )
```

The writing may take a list of numbers, but the call to `writeAtIndex` will be called with the first element only:

```
def do_stuff(index):
    writeAtIndex(index, randint(1, 100))
```

Function `writeAtIndex` takes one `int`, not a list:

```
void writeAtIndex(int index, int value)
```

That's why your output has a value on each position.

And as said by @Voo and in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html):

> The multiprocessing package offers both local and remote concurrency, effectively side-stepping the Global Interpreter Lock by using subprocesses instead of threads.

> Process objects represent activity that is run in a separate process.

So there is a `globalvar` for each process.

If you want to share data between threads you can use the [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading) module. There are details you should read though:

> due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.